# Set ADODB query timeout

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba, timeout

I am trying to forcefully get a timeout expired error message.

I have set the `Connection.CommandTimeOut` to 1, but a 20-second query gets executed without a hitch.

```vb
Public Function getdata(query As String) As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim connstring As String
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection

connstring = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=omitted;uid=omitted;pwd=omitted;database=omitted;Connect Timeout=180"
cnn.Open connstring
cnn.CommandTimeout = 1
Set getdata = New ADODB.Recordset
    getdata.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    Debug.Print cnn.CommandTimeout 'prints 1, as expected

getdata.Open query, connstring, adOpenStatic, adLockBatchOptimistic

cnn.Close
End Function
```

How do I properly set the maximum allowed time a query execution should be attempted for?

Comment: The timeout considers only network read time so, if your query is returning results within 1 second, the timeout will not occur even if the query duration is much greater.

Comment: Ah so if I understand correctly, if the query returns even just 1 of a million records within that one second, the timeout won't expire?

Comment: Correct, and also the query will not timeout if the 1M row query takes 10 minutes as long as the underlying network packets are returned within 1 second when fetched.

Comment: @DanGuzman any other methods that will help me set how long a query execution should take longest?

Comment: I think you would need to do that in the client code yourself rather than rely on the API. For example, capture the time when the query is executed and check against the current time upon each fetch.

Comment: @DanGuzman alright, shame it isn't an ADODB feature. Thanks!